# Extracting only certain characters from this string

Tags: php

I am attempting an API call and am looking to extract the values i receive into a specific format. A good example of the kind of value this API call returns can be seen below:

26_3183_1203_abc-18-2036155-o8x29ir37e_____12387_23465412

I am looking to extract out of the above string, each piece of data between the underscores using the php function strpos() but am not having much luck, so for example, I am looking to extract out the below values from the string above for use elsewhere in my code:

26
3183
1203
abc-18-2036155-o8x29ir37e
12387
23465412

Can anyone please help me out here?

Thanks in advance!
Mark

Comment: Try explode('_', $your_string) and work with array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$api_key  = "26_3183_1203_abc-18-2036155-o8x29ir37e_____12387_23465412";
$array    = explode("_", $api_key);

/*
$array[0] = "26";
$array[1] = "3183";
$array[2] = "1203";
....
*/
```

Comment: While your code likely answers the question, it is not good practice to do code only answers on Stack Overflow. Please use code blocks by intending with four spaces to make included code more readable and include a short explanation what explode does and why it is the right function for his problem.

Comment: I would do normally, but the code is pretty self explanatory

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $theString  = "26_3183_1203_abc-18-2036155-o8x29ir37e_____12387_23465412";
    $pieces = explode("_", $theString);
    echo $pieces[0]; // prints 26
    echo $pieces[1]; // prints 3183 
?>

For more info on explode function, check the below url:
http://in3.php.net/explode
```

Comment: While your code likely answers the question, it is not good practice to do code only answers on Stack Overflow.
Please use code blocks by intending with four spaces to make included code more readable and include a short explanation what explode does and why it is the right function for his problem.

Comment: i intended with four spaces already...may i know where am missing?

Comment: The first line was not intended, that is why it was not rendered as a code block.

Comment: actually i indented with four spaces in first line also, after ` symbol, but it came that way?

Comment: `-enclosed text is rendered differently than content that is intended by four spaces. Please use four spaces for code and back-ticks for highlighting individual words or classnames.

Comment: thanks for correcting me Tim Bodeit